# Subsetting Duplicates in a DataFrame without Rounding in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset, x, which contains 7 different variables. Variable 7 is a numeric class variable containing average values for criteria denoted in the first 6 variables. I am attempting to subset the data based on the criteria that there are duplicates in this dataframe, and I am only trying to retrieve the duplicates rather than the unique values. I attempted to use several different functions: filter, which, etc. all based around this basic idea:

```
    x = x[duplicated(x),]
```

But the issue is that no matter what syntax I used, the end result is a dataframe with my average values all rounded to a single digit, despite the class of that value still being numeric. Where exactly am I going wrong?

EDIT: Adding Sample Data

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5  Col6 Col7
    blue tall cold nope TRUE  no   7.8677
    blue tall cold nope TRUE  no   7.8677
    gren tall cold yes  TRUE  yes  1.2354
    purp shrt warm yes  TRUE  mybe 6.1132
    yell shrt warm nope FALSE no   5.1238
    gren tall cold yes  TRUE  yes  1.2354
```

And preferred output:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5  Col6 Col7
   blue tall cold nope TRUE  no   7.8677
   gren tall cold yes  TRUE  yes  1.2354
```

Comment: Lacking sample data, here's a stab. Under the hood, `duplicated` is converting everything to `character` and pasting things together to look for identical row-strings. This may also be related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), where `sqrt(2)^2 != 2`. Furthermore, I wonder if the problem is not that the numbers are being rounded, but just being *displayed* with a rounding.

Comment: Updated with sample data.

Comment: No idea ... given your sample data and your one-liner, I get exactly your output. I suggest instead of providing us a *representation* of your data, you provide it via `dput(head(x,n=10))` (where `n=10` gives sufficient rows).

Comment: How odd. I would post a sample of my actual data, but it is sensitive information which I am not allowed to post or upload. I can say that the data set is 1000+ observations with the same 7 variables, and the end result should be 75 observations. The issue is that all of those 75 means displayed are rounded.

Comment: I understand, and that's a common predicament. Perhaps you can come up with 10 or so rows of random data that demonstrate the problem. If you do that, you can either provide the `dput` output or just the code used to create it (and the random seed at the time, controlled with something like [`set.seed(2)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html)).

Comment: I'll see what, if anything, I can post that suffers from the same problem. If I'm unable to, I appreciate your help regardless. Thanks.